# Software serial between Arduino UNO and ESP8266 HUZZAH breakout

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am doing a task that send sensor data Through WIFI from esp to PC application to visualize it. all parts of this project done except the one that send the sensor data from UNO to ESP on software serial.

Wiring:

- connect Rx (0) of UNO to pin (12) in ESP. as Tx
- connect Tx (1) of UNO to voltage divider to take 3.3 v to ESP. pin (14) as Rx.
- ground of ESP. to Ground of UNO.
- V+ of ESP. to 3v3 of UNO.

Code:

[Attached](https://yadi.sk/d/0sOqPj_dyJDXV) two codes to test this process if it is working or not. One on ESP and another on arduino

After building I found according to the screenshow below, there is something being send because of the condition of while loop and the delay I set but the output is converted to numbers not string, random numbers !

[image]

Comment: the software serial i used : https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial

Comment: Is the Serial Monitor output coming from the Uno or the ESP8266? You should edit your post to include your sketches here on stackoverflow.

Comment: From ESP8266. Recently I think there will be one code to  this process, no two separate codes.  My main question is how to use ESP8266 as module to arduino  UNO ?!

Comment: "Recently I think there will be one code to this process, no two separate codes" What does that mean. You posted a link to two "codes", one apparently for the ESP8266, one for the Uno, now you're trying to claim there's only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - V+ of ESP. to 3v3 of UNO.

The 3v3 pin on a standard Uno will not supply enough current for an ESP8266 to work reliably.

Serial on the Uno is connected to Arduino pins 0 and 1, which you're using for output to the Serial Monitor on your computer(as well as uploading sketches). You're also using pins 0 and 1 to communicate with the ESP8266 using software serial. You can't use the same pins for both these purposes at the same time. You need to either use different pins for your software serial or, since you're currently not doing anything useful with Serial you could switch to using Serial on the Uno to communicate with the ESP8266 and remove the software serial code.

If you're going to continue to use software serial on the Uno then you should use a lower baud rate than 115200 as the Arduino SoftwareSerial library is not reliable at that speed.

I don't know what you think this code is doing:

```
char x = "ahmad,54,54,45";
while ( ESPserial.available() ) {
ESPserial.write( x );
```

but it's definitely not going to work.

The line:

```
char x = "ahmad,54,54,45";
```

is the equivalent of:

```
char x = 16;
```

Maybe you meant to use a char array:

```
char x[] = "ahmad,54,54,45";
```

However that will not be compatible with

```
ESPserial.write( x );
```

So you would either need to change it to:

```
ESPserial.print( x );
```

which will print the full string at once, or you could work through the array one character at a time:

```
ESPserial.write( x[i] );
```

The line:

```
while ( ESPserial.available() ) {
```

checks if there is incoming data available from the ESP8266 but that's never going to be true because you don't ever send any data from the ESP8266 over software serial. If it ever did receive any data then it would get permanently stuck in that while loop because you never read the received data. Then instead of reading that non-existent incoming data you write the number 16 to the ESP8266:

```
ESPserial.write( x );
```

I recommend you take the time to read the [documentation for the Arduino SoftwareSerial library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial). The same information should also apply to the [ESP8266 SoftwareSerial library you're using](https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial) on the ESP8266.